# Android: Passing Parameters Between Activities With Adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

Hope I'll succeed explain my situation the best.

I have an Activity (A) which is basically a Form to add a new item, with few text fields, time and location field. 
When clicking a setlocation button it invokes a second Activity (B) that has a list view with a customized ArrayAdapter which present suggestions for locactins. when clicking on one item (OnClickListener inside the adapter class) It need to pass it falue back to Activity A.

Call Activity B from A

```
Intent I = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TaskGeoSetActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(I, LOC_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

Setting the adapter inside Activity B

```
Adapter = new TaskGeoSubBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.sugtext, result);
Adapter.setActivity(TaskGeoSetActivity.this);
lv.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

OnClick Event within the adapter

```
public void setActivity(Activity act) {
    parentAct = act;
}

private final OnClickListener locpicker = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Address a = items.get((Integer) v.getTag());
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskAddActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Address", a);
            parentAct.setResult(parentAct.RESULT_OK, intent);
        }

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your click handler with this.

```
private final OnClickListener locpicker = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Address a = items.get((Integer) v.getTag());
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskAddActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Address", a);
        ((Activity)v.getContext()).setResult(parentAct.RESULT_OK, intent);
        ((Activity)v.getContext()).finish();
    }
}
```

In your calling activity override onActivityResult to handle the result.  OUR_REQUEST_CODE is the request code you sent when you called startActivityForResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
        case OUR_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Do something useful with data
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data back to activity A, you should be using the function `setResult` in combination with your `startActivityForResult`.

See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14118010/238180

Comment: Hi, thank you. I know that, the problem is that i need to invoke setResult within the adapter class

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the result on your `activity` B, you don't need to `Adapter.setActivity(TaskGeoSetActivity.this);`
Just `this.setResult(parentAct.RESULT_OK, intent);`:

```
private final OnClickListener locpicker = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ActivityB.this.setResult(...);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, This on click listener is inside the base adapter. "This." does not recognize ActivityB. I know that setResult from activityB will pass it back to A but how do i pass it from the Adapter?
Best regards

Comment: @BenDiamant sry, it was ActivityB.this. instead of this.ActivityB

Comment: Hi! i get "No enclosing instance of the type ActivityB is accessible in scope" error at the line of:
ActivityB.this.setResult(ActivityB.RESULT_OK, intent);

Comment: @BenDiamant oh I thought it was in activity B, it is in activity A ?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtra("Address", a);
ActivityB.this.setResult(ActivityB.RESULT_OK, intent);

Line 3 give the error